# self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView = nil crash

Tags: ios

When I used the method `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView = nil`. Then got a crash and the log was `-[__NSArrayM replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: object cannot be nil`. This problem only occurred in a little devices.

Comment: What you mean by little devices? Are you talking about device which has old iOS version? Also Have you tried to comment out this line self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView = nil and check if this line caused the error?

Comment: My crashed device version is 10.3.2. And exception occurred in this line.

Comment: What's the version of device that you are not receiving crash?

Comment: The version 11.* is ok.

Comment: Okay. Please check my answer if it's helpful.

Comment: It makes no sense to say `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView = nil`. Why would you ever say it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the crash is coming on iOS 10 and below iOS 10 devices. The reason is you might use customView while creating a `UIBarButtonItem` as like below.

```
//Example
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0)))
```

So try to set nil to `rightBarButtonItem` instead of `rightBarButtonItem?.customView = nil`.

```
//Example
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView` it will return `nil` or result in app crash.

In order to access your `customView` after added, you have to access it using `Swift` standard way:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.first?.customView
```

Check bellow answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60295524/1399938

Help vote up for other if this work for you.