# After Add a CustomView to navigationItem, CustomView always return nil

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uinavigationbar, custom-view

Bellow code is adding a customView to `navigationItem` successfully, but when trying to access the `customView` it always return `nil`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let customView = getCustomView() // supposed that the function return a custom view
    let actionButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = actionButton // successfully added customView
    print(navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView)  // print always nil
}
```

Result :

```
nil
```

Comment: You didn't define your `customView`

Comment: Can you share the complete example?

Comment: put the code of method getCustomView()

Comment: I used the same code that you have in the viewDidLoad() and it works

Comment: Is any other part of code or methods in the UIViewController modifying the navigationItem

Comment: @RohanBhale CustomView is no nil anymore ?

Comment: There is no code or method that modifying the navigationItem at all.

Comment: customView of the navitaionItem.rightBarButtonItem was not nil. After the print statement I always get a statement printed on the console:
Optional(<UIView: 0x7faa92d614b0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000038e40a0>>)

Comment: hi @RohanBhale I was not saying navitaionItem.rightBarButtonItem is not nil, it is its customView that is nil.

Comment: @vhong I clearly said customView of the navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem and not just navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem. My print statement was print(navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView)

Comment: @RohanBhale I see, it did not work for me, anyway thanks for your help. I can get it works only by trying to access it via items array.

Comment: Plus my UIViewController is an embeded UINavigationController one. I guess that why I can't access it directly.

Comment: @vhong may be you should now put the info that states your UIViewController is an embeded UINavigationController one in the question as an update and also dig deeper to find why it didnt work earlier and why it works now and put that up in the answer as an edit. Anyways glad that you found a solution. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the best way to access our `customView` (custom `rightBarButtonItem`), we have to access through Swift standard way:

After adding the customView, we can access the customView via : `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems` array only.

In my case to get customView back from navigationItem :

> let customView = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.first?.customView // access the first
>   added customView

Answer (score -1):

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue// supposed that the function return a custom view
    let actionButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = actionButton // successfully added customView
    print(navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView)
```

This works for me

Comment: I trying to access the customView, that recently added to navigationItem successfully, but when try to access them, it shows nil

Comment: probably the problem is in the method you are calling, put code for it

Comment: my issue is I wanted to get frame from customView, after added to navigation item.